# Add Composer Git Vendor Submodule to Parent Repository

Tags: php, git, github, zend-framework2, composer-php

I've added a third party library to my application using composer and it is a submodule.  I want this submodule to be available to my parent git repository so that I can push it to my git repo.  How can this be done?  I want to preserver the current submodule so that I can continue to stay updated with that library.

Comment: You'd have to delete the .git directory of the submodule.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `vendor` folder to your `.gitignore` file:

```
echo "vendor/" >> .gitignore
```

I do not completely understand why you want to use submodules, but my educated guess is that you don't need them for anything you want to do with your application and the library you are importing with Composer. Ignoring the vendor folder will make git to not mention any repositories checked out inside it as possible submodules.

Do commit your `composer.lock` file, and also avoid depending on branches of any library: Use tagged versions.